# Form submit in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a custom directive(contentData) for creating a custom form in my application. which have a template file. This template file have multiple piece of data which is control by a JOSN file.

I am trying to send from data to my controller by clicking on submit button but i am able to do that.

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/aB221u18ccNMHfJbOFDo?p=preview][1]
```

Comment: First, this is a massive junk of code that probably no one wants to look at. Cut it down to the most relevant part. Second, what is 'not working' actually? Do you get an error? Is there unwanted behaviour? What is happening?

Comment: Please have look here http://plnkr.co/edit/aB221u18ccNMHfJbOFDo?p=preview

Comment: @Rashid pluncker says plunk not found, are you sure your link is correct?

Comment: @AliAmiri please click again it open http://plnkr.co/edit/aB221u18ccNMHfJbOFDo?p=preview

Comment: I can't see any thing, maybe it's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add scope:false in the directive definition so that when any value get change inside the directive the same is reflected in the parent scope. I have added scope to false in the plnkr and the $scope.templateVariable was reflected in the parent scope.

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:false,
    templateUrl :'template.html',
    // NB: no isolated scope!!
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //console.log(attrs.yourname);
        // executes the expression on the current scope returning the result
        // and adds it to the scope
        scope.variable = scope.$eval(attrs.yourDirective);
        console.log(scope.variable);
       // scope.myfn=function(){
        //  scope.templateVariable='hello world';
        //}
    },
    // the variable is available in directive controller,
    // and can be fetched as done in link function
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs',
        function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.myfn = function(){
             $scope.templateVariable='hello world';
            //  $scope.templateVariable = $scope.infogain;
            };
            // executes the expression on the current scope returning the result
            // and adds it to the scope

            //console.log($scope.variable);
        }
     ]
};
```

[working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SMIk4khstI7L9iuI1NA?p=preview)

Comment: Thx @chuba, but my template populate as per json object and in controller i m not able to get template model value.

Comment: @Rashid, I have made change to myText input to reflect the model in the controller, the same can be replicated to all other control in the template. here is the plnkr [working plkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rtpo8BWVqc9vS6L4FkV3?p=preview)